# How do you show $x_n=n(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}-1)$ converges or not in C with the usual norm?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, convergence-divergence

I have taken the limit of $x_n$ and got $2i\pi$. Now I am stuck trying to show $|n(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}-1)-2i\pi|=0$. I am thinking I should try to write this in the form of $|a+bi|$ but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Are you willing to use L'Hospital's Rule? That will prove the limit is $2\pi i$ and you will not need to directly prove anything involving norms. Rather, those things will be a consequence of having established the limit.

Comment: Isn't it true that sequences don't always converge to their limit? I can find the limit but I feel like I need to prove the sequence converges to that limit.

Comment: @Ashley: By definition, a sequence converges if and only if it has a limit.  To say that $(x_n)$ converges means that there exists $x\in\mathbb C$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=x$.  "The limit of the sequence $(x_n)$ is $x$," and "The sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$," mean precisely the same thing.

Comment: If a sequence converges at all, then the definition of its _limit_ is the value to which it converges. And if the sequence does not converge, then the limit does not exist. (There are also sequences that are called _Cauchy_, where the terms get arbitrarily close to each other, but not necessarily to any one specific value.) The good news is that you might not have a math problem, so much as a vocabulary misunderstanding.

Comment: I see where you are coming from though, given how questions can be worded. Like, "Let $L=2$. Prove that $\frac{2n+1}{n+1}$ converges to $L$." It seems to imply that we already know the limit is $2$, and you have to prove a "separate" convergence statement. Really, the problem is calling a number by $L$ with foresight that we _will later_ know that $2$ is the $L$imit. Anyway, with your current problem all of the work for the convergence proof has already gone into the proof of L'Hospital's Theorem, and the proof that if a real function converges, then so do sequences that use that function.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(z)=e^{2\pi i z}$.  Then $\displaystyle{x_n=\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}}$.  You can therefore find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\, x_n$ by finding a derivative.

Answer (score 2):

How about using that 
$$ n(e^{2\pi i /n} -1) = \frac{e^{2\pi i /n} -1}{1/n - 0}$$
which looks a lot like a differential quotient. Hence letting $1/n \to 0$ (i.e. $ n\to \infty$) you should get
$$ n(e^{2\pi i /n} -1) \to 2\pi i $$